# java while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, exit

The input file that I am trying to read contains the amount of lines for a block of entries on the first line, and records on the subsequent lines. The file may contains many blocks like this. For example:

```
3
a b c
a b 
a c b //Three in the first line tells that there are 3 subsequent lines. 
2
a b
a b c
0 //the input ends here
```

I am trying to use a while loop to read one block at a time, process it, and then read in another block. However the code works only when there is one block. When there are multiple blocks, it freezes.. Can someone help to figure out what is wrong? Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        String number = s.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("0")){
            break;
        }else {

            int n = Integer.parseInt(number);
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
                 String letters= s.nextLine();
                 ...
                //do something to store the lines of letters 
            }
        }                   
    }   
}
```

Comment: `if (!line.equals("0"))` Shouldn't that be `if (line.equals("0"))`?

Comment: Write out in plain language what that `if` statement does.

Comment: Even the if condition is not required it hasNextLine will read till the end of file Isn't

Comment: It is important to mention in your code example how the scanner is used in the for loop - I hope you have not forgotten to do something like `s.nextLine()` to actualy advance in the file.

Comment: Thanks. yes it should be if (line.equals("0")). I edited the question. But it still doesn't work..

Comment: BTW.. You don't really need else there since break will exit the loop

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get out of a `while` loop (other than using the control conditions carefully), is to use a `break` statement.

`System.exit(0)` will shut down the Java Virtual Machine and return the status code 0 back to the operating system. That's a little drastic. And status code 0 is conventionally used to indicate success: so your return value is idiosyncratic.

That all said, your immediate problem is a typographical one, drop `!` from the `if`:

`if (line.equals("0")){`

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out that you missed a `!` when checking the value of `line`, but there's a perhaps even bigger problem with that line: you don't ever assign anything to `line`. In fact, as things stand, it shouldn't even compile, unless `line` is a class field. (But even then, the check is no use unless the value of `line` might alter throughout the loop execution.)

Comment: Thanks. Yea I missed out a line when I typed up the code here. I edited the question. But it still doesn't work for input of more than one block of information..

Comment: You've added an assignment, but it's still outside the loop, so the value of `line` won't change as the loop progresses. In other words, if the first line of the file is "0" then the program will exit straight away, and if the first line isn't "0" then that `System.exit(0)` call will never get made.

Comment: I think I put the assignment inside the for loop and the outer while loop? Sorry I don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: I thought every time the for loop executes, the scanner s.nextline() gets called, until i=n. and then it goes to the outer while loop to call the next line again. Is it not how it works?

Comment: In your code as displayed in your question, you assign to `line` once, outside both loops. You assign to `letters` inside both loops, but that's a different variable. In fact what you really want to do is exit the outer loop based on the value of `letters`, and ignore `line` completely.

Comment: The `line` variable isn't magic: it doesn't automatically update when the next line of the for comes in unless you have some code starting with `line=...`. In your case, whenever you read the next line, you update `letters`, not `line`.

Comment: Thanks! I only kept the variable numbers and move it in the while loop. However it still doesn't work for some reason. What did I do wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Both `while` and `for` loops can be stopped using the `break` statement.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(s.hasNext()) {

        int a = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

        if(a == 0) 

            break;

        else {

            for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)

            System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        }

    }
}
```

You used `System.exit(0)` instead of `break`.

`System.exit(0)` stops the Java Virtual Machine execution from loop, not `break`. So use `break` to exit the loop.